# Async Task on TryInvokeMember ( DynamicObject)

Tags: c#

I'm using a Httpclient though the TryInvokeMember. The problem is that all calls on the httpclient are made async.

- I can't call await on it as TryInvoke is a sync method.
- When i use the .Result im getting the folling error:
  *Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.*
- When i try to set the result of the task im getting the folling cast error.

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IList<THop.Food.Shared.ViewModel.Ingredients.IngredientViewModel>>'*

I can't call PostRequest as t is determined at runetime.

Is their anyway this could be fixed?

HttpProxy:

```
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using THop.Food.Client.Logic.Services;

namespace THop.Food.Client.Logic.Proxies
{
    public class HttpProxy<T> : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientService _httpClientService;
        private readonly string _controllerName;

        public HttpProxy(IHttpClientService httpClientService)
        {
            _httpClientService = httpClientService;
            _controllerName = typeof(T).Name.Remove(0, 1).Replace("Controller", string.Empty);
        }


        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting call");
            var methods = typeof(T).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == binder.Name);


            var method = methods.First(methodInfo => binder.CallInfo.ArgumentNames.All(arg => methodInfo.GetParameters().Any(x => x.Name == arg)));


            var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(HttpMethodAttribute), true) as HttpMethodAttribute;
            var route = attribute.Template ?? string.Empty;

            var returnType = method.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault() ?? method.ReturnType;

            Console.WriteLine("Routing");
            while ((route.IndexOf('{') != -1))
            {
                var indexOfStart = route.IndexOf('{');
                var indexofEnd = route.IndexOf('}');

                var propertyName = route.Substring(indexOfStart + 1, indexofEnd - 1);
                var param = method.GetParameters().First(x => x.Name == propertyName);
                route = route.Replace($"{{{propertyName}}}", args[param.Position].ToString());
            }


            switch (attribute)
            {
                case HttpPostAttribute _:
                    {
                        var bodyParam = method.GetParameters().First(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<FromBodyAttribute>() != null);
                        var body = args[bodyParam.Position];

                        var res = _httpClientService.PostRequest(_controllerName, route, body, returnType);
                        result = res;
                        return true;
                    }
                case HttpGetAttribute _:
                    var t = _httpClientService.GetRequest(_controllerName, route, returnType);
                    result = t;
                    return true;
                default:
                    result = default;
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HttpClientService

```
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public HttpClientService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<dynamic> GetRequest(string path,  Type type)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(path);
            return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync(type);
        }

        public async Task<dynamic> GetRequest(string controller, string parameter, Type type)
        {
            return await GetRequest($"{controller}/{parameter}", type);
        }}
```

Caller:

````
        {
            await base.OnInitializedAsync();

             var ingredient = await IngredientsController.Get(Id);
             Ingredient = Mapper.Map<EditIngredient>(ingredient);
        }```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow... Let's see some code!

Comment: Thanks, I added the code

Comment: So I am having problems following your code. How would you call this code? I see `HttpProxy` class, but I don't ever see it used. What have you tried to get the errors you listed. Show the code what you tried with the error under it. This way we know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The HttpProxy is mapped over the interface, and the interface is called.

I fixed the problem by making the httpclientservice call generic en calling them with getmethod en make generic.